# How to use pb_ds on the Mac M1 chip

Tags: c++, macos, c++17, gnu, apple-m1

Here is piece of C++ code below, and I'm trying to compiled it on Mac M1 chip, the error log tell me that `#include<ext/pb_ds/priority_queue.hpp>` was not supported.

I'm tried command 'brew install gcc@10', but it's not work.

Is there anything I can do to get the pb_ds files?

Thanks!

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cassert>
#include<vector>
#include<ext/pb_ds/priority_queue.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace __gnu_pbds;
const int N=100005;
int T;
int n;
vector<int>G[N];
__gnu_pbds::priority_queue<int,less<int>,pairing_heap_tag>q[N];
```

Comment: Please show the error messages verbatim.